# CMake COMMAND shell parameter substitution failing

Tags: shell, cmake

I try to create a cmake custom target to merge several .a files into a single one. Note that I cannot use the `OBJECTS`lib mode because I have a lot of 3rd party library (I'm in a complex environment, conan, cmake, etc...).

So I wrote the following

```
add_custom_target(combineall
    COMMAND echo "extract all .o files from all lib*.a file in the static folder"
    COMMAND for f in *.a ; do ar -x $f ; done
    COMMAND echo "merge all .o files in the static folder"
    COMMAND for f in *.o ; do ar -rs ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmerged.a $f ; done
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/static
    DEPENDS MyLib
    )
```

but when cmake run the `combineall` custom target I get the following error message:

> extract all .o files from all lib*.a file in the static folder
>   /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

I suppose that it come from the `$f`. I know that I could wrote a completely different cmake script iterating others the .a files using the cmake `for_each`syntax but It's not my goal here !

Regards,
Alex

Comment: It's usually better to expand your shell variables in strings, like so: `for f in *.a ; do ar -x "$f" ; done`. Don't know if that would change anything in a `cmake` context, but you can give it a try.

Comment: Hi @Nepho I already try but it fails in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to backslash-escape your semicolons, and $-escape your $. CMake is removing them from the command and so bash sees `for f in *.a do ar -x  done`, which fails with the error you're seeing.

So your target should be:

```
add_custom_target(combineall
    COMMAND echo "extract all .o files from all lib*.a file in the static folder"
    COMMAND for f in *.a \; do ar -x $$f \; done
    COMMAND echo "merge all .o files in the static folder"
    COMMAND for f in *.o \; do ar -rs ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libmerged.a $$f \; done
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/static
    DEPENDS MyLib
    )
```

Comment: Another option is to put the script into a file and invoke the script file from CMake.